# echo strings with envrionment variables from lines pulled from a file in bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk, sed, environment-variables

I have a file like so:

```
 - ${VAR1}/blah/blah:/blah1
 - ${VAR2}/blah/blah:/blah2
 - $VAR3:/blah3
```

**I ultimately need to create those three folders.**

I am using sed to extract the folder part:

```sh
$ cat test.txt |  grep -E '^ +- \$.*?:.*?$' | sed 's/.*- \(\$.*\):.*/\1/g'
```

```sh
${VAR1}/blah/blah
${VAR2}/blah/blah
$VAR3
```

I need to create those folders but I need those shell variables to expand. Right now they don't:

```sh
$ cat test.txt |  grep -E '^ +- \$.*?:.*?$' | sed 's/.*- \(\$.*\):.*/\1/g' | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

```sh
${VAR1}/blah/blah
${VAR2}/blah/blah
$VAR3
```

Is there a way to get the expanded strings so I can run `mkdir` instead of `echo` to make the folders?

Comment: What is `.*?` supposed to match? It's not valid ERE.

Comment: Doesn't it match any character? The regex seems to be working...

Comment: Then you'd write `.*`. `grep` doesn't support non-greedy quantifiers without `-P` flag.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan no, `.` matches any character. `.*?` is undefined behavior in a BRE or ERE (as supported by all standard Unix tools) as it's a repetition character (`*`) followed by another repetition character (`?`). It's "working" by accident if at all, don't rely on it, all you really need is `.*` (0 or more occurrences of any character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `bash` script with `envsubst`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
while IFS=' -:' read -r _ d _; do
   mkdir -p "$d"
done < <(envsubst < test.txt)
```

---

Alternatively use this `envsubst + awk + xargs` solution:

```sh
envsubst < text.txt |
awk -F '[-:[:blank:]]+' -v ORS='\0' '{print $2}' |
xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all those variables should be exported to be accessible from your script. Then you could just use the `cut` and `tr` commands combination to extract dir name in a loop like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

while read -r LINE; do
    echo "$LINE" |  cut -d ':' -f 1 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '-' 
done < test.txt
```

Comment: The variables are exported. But if the read line references a variable name, the output will not be pulled in.